# CollapsingToolbarLayout : Font size with custom fonts

Tags: android, fonts, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-typeface

I am using a CollapsingToolbarLayout for which I then change the Typeface using the method below:

```
if (toolbarTypeface == null) {
            toolbarTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/FrutigerLTStd-Light.otf");
}
collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(toolbarTypeface);
collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTypeface(toolbarTypeface);
```

My issue is I can't find anyway of changing the **font size**.  Most CollapsingToolbarLayout examples use a theme to change the font size, however as I am using loading up a font from assets, I am not sure how that works.